# How to get mysqli table variable into $message

Tags: php, sql, email, mysqli

I have a reminder mail function on my website. I get the email adresses from my sql database, and it is working just fine. But I also have an item no. from the database that I have to put in the mail to tell the users which item have expired and need to be returned. I have the mail text inside a $message. But I don´t know how to get the item no. variable from the database inside the message. I have been looking around for examples and tutorials, but nothing works. This is what I´ve got so far. Any one of you got some advice?

```
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $message = "Dear user \n\n Please return item no. $row['Item_no'] as soon as possible.  \n\n Regards Thomas";
        //echo ($message);
        mail ( $row['Email'], "Reminder", $message );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to [concatenate](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-string-concatenation.html) `$row['Item_no']` inside your echo.

```
 $message = "Dear user \n\n Please return item no. " . $row['Item_no'] . " as soon as possible.  \n\n Regards Thomas";
```

Comment: No problem mate. Goodluck. Don't forget to tick :)